# Django Rest Framework - Filtering against the URL - TypeError as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

So I'm trying to use Django Rest Framework. It's going to act as a REST API for an Ionic hybrid app. I need to be able to send a request from the app with a street name parameter (based on the nearest street from the users GPS location), which return data containing the that street name. I'm trying to follow the [Filtering against the URL](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-url) guide in the docs.

My code looks like this:

```
**urls.py**
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'notes', views.NoteView, base_name='notes')

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),namespace='rest_framework')),
                   url('^notes/(?P<location>.+)/$', views.NoteView.as_view()),
)

**serializers.py**
class NoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    place = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ('text_content', 'from_date', 'place')

**views.py**
class NoteView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = NoteSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        location = self.kwargs['location']
        wreturn Note.objects.filter(place__name__contains=location)
```

I'm not strong in regex, but I imagine that I need to put in localhost/api/notes/streetname/ to query the api for data with that street name?

What happens is that I get the error:
TypeError at /api/notes/Vestergade/
as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

Stacktrace:

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/notes/Vestergade/

Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'api')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/andersravn/Projekter/laverapi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  119.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/Users/andersravn/Projekter/laverapi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  366.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/Users/andersravn/Projekter/laverapi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  402.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/Users/andersravn/Projekter/laverapi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  396.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/Users/andersravn/Projekter/laverapi/citystoriesapi/citystoriesapi/urls.py" in <module>
  17.                        url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
File "/Users/andersravn/Projekter/laverapi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py" in urls
  79.             self._urls = patterns('', *self.get_urls())
File "/Users/andersravn/Projekter/laverapi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py" in get_urls
  315.         default_urls = super(DefaultRouter, self).get_urls()
File "/Users/andersravn/Projekter/laverapi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py" in get_urls
  256.                 view = viewset.as_view(mapping, **route.initkwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/notes/Vestergade/
Exception Value: as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

I can't seem to figure out where these 3 arguments are given.

Comment: Remove the Noteview.as_view() from your urls, you already included the view on the router

Comment: Do I need to remove the whole line from urlpatterns?

Comment: Yes, and then look into using django filters with rest framework to against the url

Comment: Deleting the line gives me the same exception. I'm not sure what you mean with "django filters with rest framework to against the url"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just stumbled upon this trying to limit my API's requests to the current user.

It's about the type of view: `generics.ListAPIView`. It shouldn't be a View, but a ViewSet – check this issue [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/933)

Change it to `viewsets.ModelViewSet` or something similar.

Comment: The real answer. Thank you.

Comment: How did you achieve that the 'list' will support update/patch and not /me/(pk) ?

Answer (score -1):

Two things I notice which I think can help you in fixing the issue.

1. Get rid of `router.register(r'notes', views.NoteView, base_name='notes')`
2. Either add `/api` in `url('^notes/(?P<location>.+)/$', views.NoteView.as_view()),` or simply access `/notes/*LOCATION*`

Comment: is there any solution to get this working without deleting router.register?

Comment: Can you explain as to why you would be interested in keeping duplicate url pattern/regex? My humble suggestion was applicable to single (router.register) line as it was duplicated.

Can you provide minimal urls.py?